# Thymeleaf th:each create a new page when content filled the page

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have a very easy **list** fragment:

```
<html>

    <header>
        ...
    </header>
    
    <ul>
        <li> ... </li>
        <li> ... </li>
        ...
    </ul>
    
    <footer>
        ...
    </footer>

</html>
```

This is a fragment generated 2 times using th:replace in the main html file. Here is the code:

```
<div class="content-page">
    <header th:replace=“~{fragments.html :: header}"></header>
    <footer th:replace=“~{fragments.html :: footer}"></footer>
    <th:block th:replace="~{fragments.html :: list1}"></th:block>
</div>

<div class="content-page">
    <header th:replace=“~{fragments.html :: header}"></header>
    <footer th:replace=“~{fragments.html :: footer}"></footer>
    <th:block th:replace="~{fragments.html :: list2}"></th:block>
</div>
```

Now I want to generate pass dynamic data for ul, I will pass `List<String> dataToDisplay` param from Java, which will contain data for my `<ul>`. But I don't know how and when I should create new page in html so that the content fits my page. I will have smth like this:

```
<div class="content-page" th:each="SOME_CONDITION">
    <header th:replace=“~{fragments.html :: header}"></header>
    <footer th:replace=“~{fragments.html :: footer}"></footer>
    <th:block th:replace="~{fragments.html :: list(dataToDisplay)}"></th:block>
</div>
```

How can I decide how many times I will generate the "content-page"? What would be the SOME_CONDITION?

How should I iterate correctly the string list? What would be the correlation between my list and SOME_CONDITION? How to keep track correctly the list index to be used in the list fragment?

Maybe I could limit each "content-page" to a certain number of string chars per page? (but I am not sure how to handle the line breaks in this case)

Thanks!

Comment: "_so that the content fits my page_" - What does "page" mean here? The size of the browser's viewport? A pre-determined number of list items? Something else?

Comment: If you had to determine `SOME_CONDITION` manually (just to build the HTML) for a specific set of data, how would you do it? What steps would you follow?

Comment: @andrewJames I just have 100 line items which should go between footer and header. in some cases I can fit list items on the page if some elements are 3-5 lines long, or about 30 list items if the text to display is small. Would it be an option to put the condition based on the displayed text characters count?

Comment: manually I would put several list items, check visually if it fits the page and there are no overlaps, and add several more items until the page is full, after I will create a new page